# For Loop in R to find duplicates in single vector WITHOUT built-in functions

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I found this as an interview question and can't seem to work a solution. You can't use any built in R functions.

```
x <- c(77, 12, 4, 8, 77, 2, 4, 12)
answer <- FALSE #int the answer to FALSE
```

The way I look at it is the loop takes 77 and compares it to the right. Once it see's the next 77 at x[5], it should return answer <- TRUE and the code should stop completely. But pretend the first number isn't a duplicate, then the next time through it doesn't need to look at x[1] again since its already done x[1] vs x[2] on the first pass through.

This is what I've worked on but can't seem to get it. I have n <- length(x). I've added a variable count <- 0 but within the first loop it increments by 1. Then in the next loop I'm saying 'look from count to the end', but not sure if this is correct either. What seems to happen is it doesn't break away at the first duplicate, then gets to the last index in x and compares it against itself, thus returns TRUE, which is incorrect.

```
for (i in 1:n){  #wasn't sure if this should be 2:n?
count <- count +1
  for (stuff in (count:n)){ 
    if (stuff){
      answer <- TRUE
      break #I thought this would break the entire code when it see's x[1] vs x[5] which is 77 duplicate
    }
  }
}
answer
```

Comment: Do you want to get the amount of duplicates? Or do you want to get for each number the amount of repetitions?

Comment: What constitutes a Built in R function? `if()` and `for()`  are both technically built in functions.

Comment: @SantiagoI.Hurtado If there is a duplicate then answer should be TRUE. I don't need the number of duplicates or which number is duplicated. I can't use %in% since that is an R function

Comment: @DanielO Sorry I should have been more clear, I can use if() and for() but not any();%in% or is.element()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
x <- c(77, 12, 4, 8, 77, 2, 4, 12)
answer <- FALSE
n <- length(x)
for(count in 1:n){
  for(compare in x[-count]){
    if(x[count] == compare){
      answer <- TRUE
      break()
    }
  }
  if(answer){break()}
}
```

Comment: This seems to accomplish the task, thank you. Can you explain what the "-" in x[-count] is doing?

Comment: the minus means that it will used all x vector without the "count"

Answer (score 0):

The following :

```
!all(duplicated(x))
```

Seems to work, and does not use either `any()`, `is.element` or `%in%` functions. If you want your teacher to become smarter and learn the definition of 'builtin' functions, you could answer that :)

Edit : Otherwise, a good algorithm can be found [there](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-duplicates-in-on-time-and-constant-extra-space/) in O(n) time and O(1) extra space.

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
for (i in x) {
  repeats <- length(x[x == i])
  if (repeats < 2) {

  } else {
    print(paste(i, "has duplicates"))
    break
  }
}
```

Comment: I agree this will work, however I cannot use %in%. I like your idea of using if (repeats < 2) though, I'll work on something similar. If you can think of a way without %in% I'd appreciate it

Comment: can you use 'sum'?

Comment: you can define 'repeats' in the same loop as repeats <- length(x[x == i]). But then again, can you use length()?

Comment: Using sum and length is permitted. The interview question said 'No %in% or is.element functions".

Comment: then this will work :) same loop but with repeats <- length(x[x == i])